# Patent D698,996 S

Tags: baorenzong, gmail.com

Sorry to disturb you, I am an Amazon seller and have infringed your appearance patent D698,996 S
You are the owner of this patent. Can you license it for my Amazon store? I need a power of attorney for this appearance patent D698,996 S. Can you help me? I am willing to pay you, please contact me in time if you see the information, thank you very much.
wish you a happy lifeMy email: baorenzong@gmail.com
bao

Comment: This site is not a way to directly communicate with the patent owner.

Answer (score 2):

This site is not the inventor of the cited design patent. The inventor on design patent [D698,996](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD698996S1/en?oq=D698%2C996) is Noam Krasniansky of Los Angeles, CA. If you have been contacted regarding patent infringement then you should respond to that communication as it will likely represent the patent holder. Otherwise you should try to search for a Noam Krasniansky of Los Angeles, CA though other means such as Google.

Comment: You may also find contact information for the inventor or a patent attorney or patent agent by looking up the application 29/418,268 in Public PAIR. https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I did look on the Public Pair and didn't see any more info. Pair is down right now, but when its up, I'll check more closely.